# Where does magento get the value of the "updated" column to display in adminhtml->system->index mgm?

Tags: magento2, indexer

The dates shown on the index management adminhtml page are not the same as what can be found in the table: indexer_state.updated.  I cannot seem to track down the dates this grid is pulling.  I am specifically looking for the cataloginventory_stock updated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

magento_indexer/Model/Indexer/getLatestUpdated():

`public function getLatestUpdated()
    {
        if ($this->getView()->isEnabled() && $this->getView()->getUpdated()) {
            if (!$this->getState()->getUpdated()) {
                return $this->getView()->getUpdated();
            }
            $indexerUpdatedDate = new \DateTime($this->getState()->getUpdated());
            $viewUpdatedDate = new \DateTime($this->getView()->getUpdated());
            if ($viewUpdatedDate > $indexerUpdatedDate) {
                return $this->getView()->getUpdated();
            }
        }
        return $this->getState()->getUpdated();
    }`